# bind() call in tcp client

Tags: c, sockets, proxy, network-programming, centos6

I am trying to change the source ip address for a tcp packet. Code snippet as given bellow

```
 bzero(&clientaddr,sizeof(clientaddr));
 clientaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 clientaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("172.16.2.10");
 clientaddr.sin_port=htons(8080);
 if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr, 
   sizeof(clientaddr)) < 0) 
{
    perror("bind");
}
```

Binding a particular port is working fine, 
  but when i tried to bind with a diffrent ip adress, the bind is failing with error

```
bind: Cannot assign requested address
```

I also tried by setting the socket option as follows,]

```
setsockopt (sockfd, SOL_IP, IP_TRANSPARENT, &n1, sizeof(int));*
```

then also its failing with same error.

How could i change my source ip address for packet, originated from my PC.
Please help me, its for a proxy application.

**OS** :Linux 2.6.37-tproxy #1 SMP Wed Apr 3 23:34:00 IST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mention your kernel and OS version please..

Comment: Not sure, but you probably have to use raw sockets to do this.

Comment: @Barmar If am not wrong, I have seen this possible in CentOS/RHEL 6.0 in the same way OP did

Comment: @VoidPointer kernel version is 2.6.37

Comment: @VoidPointer I am using CentOS 6.3, is it a problem with this?

Comment: No probs I guess, if your kernel supports it. I dont have much experience on this. Thought this system info would help others to help you..

Comment: Did you run your application as root or with a user having the CAP_NET_ADMIN capability? What was the errno error set by setsockopt, if any? I assume you have read [http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.10/Documentation/networking/tproxy.txt](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.10/Documentation/networking/tproxy.txt) and are following it. I probably can not help much more, without some more exact error or more code (preferrably [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: yes, am running my aplication as root user only.

Comment: How about the rrno from setsockopt?

Comment: What is the IP Address with which it gives error?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a raw socket and create the ip and tcp headers (where you will be able to set the desired IP Address (spoofing).

```
raw_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
```

You can check the linux manual page `man 7 raw`

Answer (score 0):

You can only `bind()` to an IP address that is local to your computer, i.e. implemented by one of your network interfaces.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Linux transparent proxy functionality? See the tproxy.txt in kernel documenttion and `man 7 ip` at IP_TRANSPARENT option.